# A question regarding supremum of bounded sets.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, supremum-and-infimum

I'm clear with the definition of supremum and bounded sets. But for some reason, this statement in my lecture notes given by my Prof, doesnt seem to make sense.

> Let $X = [0, 1) ∪ (2, 3]$. In this example the subset $[0, 1)$ is
>   bounded above but it has no sup.

My question: Isn't 1 the supremum for $[0,1)$ ?

Answer (score 4):

The issue here is when taking the $\sup$ you need to refer to the space you're in. Your space $X = [0, 1) \cup (2, 3]$ does not contain $1$ so $1$ cannot be the $\sup$ (in some sense claiming it's $1$ is as good as claiming it's *elephant*). It's bounded since
$$
\forall x \in [0, 1) \; 0 \le x < 2.5
$$
and both $0, 2.5$ are in your space.

Comment: I'm not really if 1 has to be in the space. Consider the sequence for instance $a_n = 1/n$. We know, the sequence is bounded and we have infumum at $0$ even though $0$ isn't in the set. Can't we use a similar argument here?

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep you need to tell me what space you're working in. If your entire space is $(0,1]$ then no the inf does not exist, nor is it $0$. If your space is $[0,1]$ or anything bigger then yes the inf would be $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Does your professor maybe mean that $[0, 1)$ doesn't contain its supremum? It's axiomatic that every bounded subset of the reals has a supremum and infimum within the reals.

To specifically answer your question: yes, $\sup [0, 1) = 1$.

Comment: No, he didn't write anything of that sort.I guess I was right, I'll cross check with him again. Thanks! :)

Comment: @SaiKrishnaDeep Presumably your professor intends $X$ to be regarded as a topological space under the subspace topology.  In this space, $[0,1)$ is indeed bounded but has no supremum.

Comment: This is not axiomatic if you define the reals as Dedekind cuts.